# R Shiny rAmCharts angular gauge x value not appearing as numeric

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a shiny app of an angular gauge with rAmCharts built in shiny features. I keep getting the error `x must be of class 'numeric' instead of 'character'`
when I try to enter an input variable for the x value of amAngularGauge. That is my main problem. Another side problem is that I would like the background to be black but there's a white block around the gauge that appears which I do not know how to fix. Here's my code

```
library(shiny)
library(rAmCharts)
library(shinythemes)




choices = data.frame(var = c("Whiskey", "Pure Alc", "Wine", "Beer"), 
                     num = c(40, 95, 10, 5))

lc = as.list(choices$num)

names(lc) = choices$var

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  selectInput("drink", "Choose your drink...", choices = lc),
  amChartsOutput("gauge")


)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$gauge = renderAmCharts({
    amAngularGauge(input$drink, 
                   bands = data.frame(start = c(0, 50), 
                                      end = c(50, 100),
                                      color = c("#0000FF", "#ea3838"),
                                      step = 20), 
                   text = "%")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `as.numeric(input$drink)` in `amAngularGauge` function

Comment: Also, if the background color is black you wont be able to see the numeric values in your gauge pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it was just a simple fix

Answer (score 1):

As per comments:

```
library(shiny)
library(rAmCharts)
library(shinythemes)

choices = data.frame(var = c("Whiskey", "Pure Alc", "Wine", "Beer"), num = c(40, 95, 10, 5))
lc = as.list(choices$num)
names(lc) = choices$var

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  column(3,selectInput("drink", "Choose your drink...", choices = lc)),
  column(3,br(),amChartsOutput("gauge",width = 300,height = 250))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$gauge = renderAmCharts({
    amAngularGauge(as.numeric(input$drink), 
                   bands = data.frame(start = c(0, 50), 
                                      end = c(50, 100),
                                      color = c("#0000FF", "#ea3838"),
                                      step = 20), text = "%")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]